# Schema violation exception when exporting to LDAP is enabled

Tags: ldap, liferay, schema

I have configured Liferay to use LDAP server which works fine as long as Import is enabled.
As soon as I switch on Export enabled option,and user tries to login it throws exception.Strangely the user from Liferay is exported to LDAP server.

> *Caused by: **javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP:
>   error code 67 - NOT_ALLOWED_ON_RDN: failed for MessageType** :
>   MODIFY_REQUEST_Message ID : 6_    Modify Request_        Object :
>   'cn=johndoe+mail=johndoeldap@liferay.com+sn=doe,dc=example,dc=com'_
>
>   Modification[0]_                Operation :  replace_
>
>   Modification_sn: doe            Modification[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzmpf.png)_
>
>   Operation :  replace_                Modification_sn: doe
>
>   Modification[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25UZN.png)_                Operation :  replace_
>
>   Modification_givenName: johndoe            Modification[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBZak.png)_
>
>   Operation :  replace_                Modification_mail:
>   johndoeldap@liferay.com            Modification[4]_
>
>   Operation :  replace_                Modification_cn: doe
>   doeorg.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.ModifyRequestImpl@32d7606a:
>   ERR_62 Entry
>   **cn=johndoe+mail=johndoeldap@liferay.com+sn=doe,dc=example,dc=com does**
>   **not have the cn attributeType, which is part of the RDN**";]; remaining
>   name
>   'cn=johndoe+mail=johndoeldap@liferay.com+sn=doe,dc=example,dc=com'
>   [Sanitized]*

Post configuring LDAP on liferay,I am able to correctly connect to LDAP and view users too.

**Below is the user mapping configuration**

[image]

**Below is export and Group mapping config**

[image]

**LDAP config**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it sorted up by correcting the User field mapping.
While importing,data was imported from LDAP without any exceptions but on the other hand,while exporting the data to LDAP,there was duplicacy in terms of 'cn' attribute being used multiple times for mapping(both for Screen name and Full name),which must have been used uniquely.So even though the user data is exported from liferay,yet this led to SchmenaViolationException and did not allow user to login in to portal.